# Eurojackpot lottery probability

Tags: probability

Can someone explain the probability of Eurojackpot?
The goal is to match 5 correct numbers out of 50 plus another 2 supplementary numbers out of another 8.

I agree with Class 1, but not with Class 2:

```
Class       Numbers Probability of winning
1 (jackpot)  5 + 2          1 : 59 325 280
2            5 + 1          1 : 4 943 773

My calculation
Class 1: (50:5)*(49:4)*(48:3)*(47:2)*(46:1)*(8:2)*(7:1) = 59 325 280
Class 2: (50:5)*(49:4)*(48:3)*(47:2)*(46:1)*(7:1)       = 14 831 320
```

[website](http://www.euro-jackpot.org/en)

Comment: Heuristically speaking: you still can choose 2 numbers from 8 to get one of them right, that increases your chances!
Mathematically speaking: until I come up with an answer, Im sure someone else will beat me at it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of matching exactly one number in the supplementary jackpot is not 1/7.  It is actually 12/28.  Think about this.  So if you multiply your probability by 84/28, you get the right answer.  Although the actual answer is 1 out of (4 943 773 + 1/3), so some rounding was done.

Comment: So i have to use (50:5)*(49:4)*(48:3)*(47:2)*(46:1)*(7:3), but why? I got a pool of 7 and have to match 1 number?

Comment: As far as I understand you have a pool of 8, choose 2 to get one correct. Is that wrong?!

Comment: $12/28=2\binom{6}{1} / \binom{8}{2}$.

Comment: In words, choose which of your two numbers you want to match, and then choose which of the other six numbers to not match.  This gives 12.  Divide by the $\binom{8}{2}=28$ total possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class       Numbers Probability of winning
1 (jackpot)  5 + 2          1 : 59 325 280
2            5 + 1          1 : 4 943 773

My calculation
Class 1: (50:5)*(49:4)*(48:3)*(47:2)*(46:1)*(8:2)*(7:1) = 59 325 280
Class 2: (50:5)*(49:4)*(48:3)*(47:2)*(46:1)*(8:2)*(7:6)*2 = .....
```

I changed the second Class to what in my believe would be correct.
The last times 2 is because of the order that your last 2 numbers are picked Wrong-Right or Right-Wrong

Comment: The second case does take into account that you don't win the ultimate jackpot. Therefore you should also take one of the wrong numbers with probability 7:6.

Comment: probability 7:6 > 1?

Comment: it's to be read as 6 divided by 7. I just used the same notation as Tony Huynh

Comment: but (8:2)*(7:6) is wrong

Comment: why? It stated *2 also

Comment: see the 12/28 comment of Tony Huynh

Comment: $\frac{2*6*2}{8*7} = \frac{12}{28}$

Comment: Yes, but $\frac{2*6*2}{8*7} \neq \frac{8*7*2}{2*6}$